# How to mock java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream using JUnit, PowerMock and/or EasyMock on Java8?

Tags: java, java-8, junit4, powermock, easymock

I want to test `StreamDecorator` class:

```
public interface IDecorator {
        default InputStream decorateStream() {
            if("gzip".equalsIgnoreCase(getEncoding())) {
                return new GZIPInputStream(getInputStream());
            }
            return is;
        }

        String getEncoding();

        InputStream getInputStream();
}

public class StreamDecorator implements IDecorator {
    private final InputStream is;
    private final String encoding;

    public StreamDecorator(InputStream is, String encoding) {
        this.is = is;
        this.encoding = encoding;
    }

    public String getEncoding() {
        return encoding;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return is;
    }
}
```

To test it, I have written the following test case:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestStreamDecorator {
    @Test
    @PrepareForTest(value = { GZIPInputStream.class })
    public void testDecorateStream() throws Exception {
        InputStream mockInputStream = PowerMock.createMock(InputStream.class);
        EasyMock.expect(mockInputStream.read()).andReturn(-1);
        PowerMock.replay(mockInputStream);

        GZIPInputStream gzip = PowerMock.createMock(GZIPInputStream.class);
        PowerMock.expectNew(GZIPInputStream.class, mockInputStream).andReturn(gzip);
        PowerMock.expectNew(GZIPInputStream.class, mockInputStream, 512).andReturn(gzip);
        PowerMock.replay(gzip);
        PowerMock.replay(GZIPInputStream.class);

        StreamDecorator inStreamDecorator = new StreamDecorator(mockInputStream, "gzip");

        assertEquals(gzip, inStreamDecorator.decorateStream());

        PowerMock.verify(mockInputStream, gzip, GZIPInputStream.class);
    }
}
```

When I run the unit test, I get java.io.EOFException (see below).
I know the reason for this exception -- it is because in second statement in TestStreamDecorator.testDecorateStream() method I'm returning -1 for InputStream.read().

But, my question is why is it even getting called when I have mocked the constructors (i.e. new instances)?

Also, I have tried mocking private readHeader() method of GZIPInputStream -- but getting different exception in another private method.
So, I guess, I'm doing something wrong.

===================== Exception =====================

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:268)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:258)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:164)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91)
    ...
```

My guess is PowerMock has some issues with Java 8 default methods. Anything in that direction?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually verifying  the mock in your last line of test case which is why you are getting the exception
Delete last two lines of your test and add this and you test case passes

```
     assertEquals(mockInputStream, inStreamDecorator.decorateStream());
```

Comment: Still not working, getting same exception. However, I have changed the assertion (edited).

Comment: Did you also try commenting out the verify statement in the last line and then execute your test.?

Comment: Yes I did remove verify statement -- same exception.

Comment: I replaced last two lines of your test case with  following assertEquals(mockInputStream, inStreamDecorator.decorateStream());

//PowerMock.verify(mockInputStream, gzip, GZIPInputStream.class); and it worked.

Comment: really sorry actually there is more to it. It's is on Java8 and looks like something to do with default methods. Updated the question.